# Prevent browser process from being closed on mobile

Tags: android, ios, progressive-web-apps, web-wake-lock

I'm trying to build a timer PWA (mostly for mobile devices), which notifies the user when a certain amount of time has passed.
(The users will know this and want it to happen - so asking for permission wouldn't be a problem.)

This works fine was long as the users actually stays on the page, keeps the browser open and doesn't lock the screen.

With the [Wakelock API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Wake_Lock_API) I can prevent the screen from locking itself - if we're on a device and in a browser which support that.
(Sadly, [many don't](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_wakelock).)
The [NoSleep.js library](https://github.com/richtr/NoSleep.js/) adds support for more devices by playing a video which the user doesn't see.
So that's something.

However, if the user actively enables the lockscreen (which many do instinctively when, say, putting their phones into their pockets) the process will be paused by iOS or Android after a while.
Which means, that the notification will be delayed until the user opens the browser again.
This may be much later, thereby defeating the whole purpose of this app.

If I were developing a native app, I could use something like a matching [UIBackgroundMode](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW22) or [Background Fetch](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/updating_your_app_with_background_app_refresh) on iOS or a [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) on Android.
However, building this as a native app would not have the advantages of a PWA, such as that no installation is required or that we can update the app at will.

From what I understand, many (all?) browser makers don't seem to want websites to be able to run in the background.
Is there a way to build this kind of PWA nevertheless?
Or would I have to switch to building a native app?
(Which may still have fight the OS, as explained on pages such as [dontkillmyapp.com](https://dontkillmyapp.com/).)

Comment: Keeping device awake for whole time doing nothing is bad idea because of battery drain. Consider using scheduled notification which is supported by most browsers and won't require even keeping browser open

Comment: @DimaRostopira I agree, that this would be a considerable drain on the battery. For the specific use case which I have in mind this would be acceptable, though of course an alternative which doesn't have this problem would be better. As to scheduled notifications, I'm guessing you mean notification triggers (https://web.dev/notification-triggers/)? If so, those seem to still be in development and not widely supported. Therefore, we can't really rely on them. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

You could accomplish this using [Notification Triggers](https://web.dev/notification-triggers/). They're currently only available as an origin trial in Chrome, but this is one of the primary use cases they were designed for.

With notification triggers, you can set a specific time for the notification to 'fire', for example, the end of your timer. It will then wake up the service worker, and allow you to show a notification to the user.

For example:

```js
const createScheduledNotification = async (tag, title, timestamp) => {
  const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration();
  registration.showNotification(title, {
    tag: tag,
    body: "The 30 second timer is up!",
    showTrigger: new TimestampTrigger(timestamp + 30 * 1000)
  });
};
```

Comment: This looks like a very good solution for devices, where this functionality is available. However until it's supported by all major mobile browsers (including Safari on iOS), this sadly won't be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a job for Serviceworker!
The app can close itself, but the serviceworker can run, monitor time and send Notifications to your user

Comment: Please consider adding more information to your answer to clarify how to use it and how it solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

On android you need an active notification object for any background tasks from within the browser.

If you open a music website in a browser for example you get a notification for the mediaplayer, so it can still run when the browser app is in the background or even if the phone is locked. This works for sites like youtube, soundcloud e.t.c. in android chrome with desktop mode.

So yeah you can do it. But you need an active notification object, since android background services for ALL apps are paused or killed after a short time if they don't attach themselves to a notification.

In your case the PWA should spawn a notification message firstly and attach a background worker process to that notification id. I don't know how to do that in your PWA, but i guess you can find how to do that by looking at some
mediaplayer apps.